# How does python logging level interact with logging.info()?

Tags: python, logging

Is this a bug?  setLevel seems to set the appropriate level, but logging.info has no effect:

```
>>> import logging
>>> logger=logging.getLogger()
>>> logger.warning('foo')
foo
>>> logger.info('foo')
>>> logger.getEffectiveLevel()
20  # this is logging.INFO.  Why didn't .info() work?
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> logger.getEffectiveLevel()
20
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logger.info('foo')
>>> logger.getEffectiveLevel()
10
```

Comment: Maybe it's a down-level bug. python --version:  Python 3.6.5 :: Anaconda, Inc.

Comment: You need to a logging handler with level info attached to the logger.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. If this is the case, IMO getEffectiveLevel has a bug- it's not returning the logging level that's actually being applied.

Comment: Maybe this flowchart from the docs makes things easier to understand: https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/logging.html#logging-flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of any logging configuration, logging uses a [last-resort handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.lastResort) that handles only messages of level `WARNING` and above.

If you run

```
logging.basicConfig()
```

it will behave as expected.